# Unable to access kubernates pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I follow below steps to deploy my custom jar

1)- I created on docker image through the below docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9
LABEL MAINTAINER DINESH
LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="First image with Dockerfile & DINESH."
RUN mkdir  /app
COPY LoginService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["java", "-jar", "LoginService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

2)- Deploy on kubernetes with the below deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: load-balancer-example
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: load-balancer-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: localhost:5000/my-image:latest
        name: hello-world
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

3)- Exposed as service with the below command

```
minikube tunnel
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --name=my-service --port=8000 --target-port=8000
```

4)- Output of the kubectl describe svc my-service

```
<strong>
Name:                     my-service<br> 
Namespace:                default<br> 
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=load-balancer-example<br> 
Annotations:              <none><br> 
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=load-balancer-example<br> 
Type:                     LoadBalancer<br> 
IP:                       10.96.142.93<br> 
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.96.142.93<br> 
Port:                     <unset>  8000/TCP<br> 
TargetPort:               8000/TCP<br> 
NodePort:                 <unset>  31284/TCP<br> 
Endpoints:                172.18.0.7:8000,172.18.0.8:8000<br> 
Session Affinity:         None<br> 
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster<br> 
Events:                   <none><br> </strong>
```

POD is in running state

I m trying to access the pod using "10.96.142.93" as given in the http://10.96.142.93:8090 my loginservice is started on 8090 PORT, BUT i am unable to access pod plz help

Comment: In your manifsts above there is not mention of 8090 port mapping, port 8000 is mapped to targetPort 8000.

Comment: i tried with this command kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --name=my-service --port=8000 --target-port=8090 but not able to access.

Comment: Yes, use port 8000 as we use service (an abstraction) to access pods and your service is exposed at port 8000 which routes your traffic to pods running on 8090 port. And if you're using type LoadBalancer in Minikube then you've to use `minikube service <svc-name>` to access it

Comment: still unable to access pod. run this command "kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --name=my-service --port=8000 --target-port=8090" and then ran minikube service my-service got the below output |-----------|------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| NAMESPACE     |    NAME | TARGET PORT |           URL           |
|-----------|------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| default | my-service |        8000 | http://172.17.0.2:30242 |
|-----------|------------|-------------|-------------------------| But still unable to fetch pod

Comment: are you able to access it from another pod via curl using pod ip directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to access on nodeport `localhost:31284` and please use service type as `NodePort` instead of `LoadBalancer` because loadbalancer service type mostly used on cloud level.

and Use Target-Port as same port you configured on pod definition yaml file.

so your url should be  `http://10.96.142.93:8000`

or another way you can be by using port-forward

`kubectl port-forward pod_name 80:8000` this will map pod port to localhost port

Then access it on `http://localhost:80`

Comment: i tried with this command kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=my-service --port=8000 --target-port=8090 but not able to access.                        I am beginner plz let me know what is pod definition file.

Comment: @Dewa what is the nodePort ip now? describe the service now and get the nodeport ip and then go to ```localhost:nodeportip```

Comment: @Dewa Your expose command is wrong should be like this  ```kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=my-service --port=8000 --target-port=8000``` containerport and target-port should be same

Comment: And now do ```kubectl describe svc service_name``` and get the nodeport ip and then go to ```localhost:nodeportip```

Comment: I tried the same command but unable to access localhost:32202. my service is running on 8090 port.

Comment: @Dewa are you sure your applictaion listen on 8090? if so please add ```EXPOSE 8090``` to your dockerfile just above the CMD command and then add containerPort 8090 in pod defination yaml file and use the same target-Port in service. I am quite sure it will work.

Comment: As u suggested i cnaged Docker file
1)- "EXPOSE 8090" above the command in Docker file

2)-  in Deployment file
     ports:
        - containerPort: 8090

3)- create deployment using "kubectl apply -f loginServiceDeployment.yaml"

4)- kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=my-service --port=8000 --target-port=8090
5)- http://localhost:30367/ tried to access with this url 

but not accible

Comment: @Dewa Could you try to use `minikube service my-service`? What is your minikube ip? You can get it with `minikube ip`.

Comment: @DashrathMundkar : Ur Suggestion was very helpful, now i can access my service which is deployed inside pod using minikube IP but not from the local host. i Followed these steps "containerPort 8090 in pod defination yaml file and use the same target-Port in service"  Thanks A Lot :-)

Comment: @Dewa if my solution worked then please accept the answer so that other might get help from it!!

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes loadbalancer type service is provided only in places such as aws and gcp. Use metallb for use in an on-premises environment.

If not, try modifying the service type to Nodeport and accessing `http://localhost:31284`